# ImportError: cannot import name 'Users' from partially initialized module tasks file

Tags: django, django-models, celery, django-celery

ImportError: cannot import name 'Users' from partially initialized module 'users.models

```
from .models import Users
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from server import settings


@shared_task()
def send_mail_task(user_id):
    user = Users.objects.get(id=user_id)

    send_mail(
        subject='Congratulations!',
        message=f'Congratulations {user.username}',
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        recipient_list=["waelelsafty07@gmail.com", ],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
    print('Email sent successfully')
    return f'Email sent successfully'
```

checking installing celery

Answer (score 1):

I import my model in this way:

`model = apps.get_model(app_label='users', model_name='users')`

when the users is name the folder

Answer (score 0):

could you post your working directory so i can see where is the files are
if you didnt customize the user model then use

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: I created app users inheritance from an abstractuser class  
```
users/
         models.py
         tasks.py

```